# How to apply transformations to empties?

Tags: python, objects, transforms, linked-data

In `Blender 2.81`, I have a linked collection, and I want to apply a transformation over it. In the UI I just select the empty , so when I scale, translate or rotate the `empty` the liked data experiences the transformations too.

By the other hand, to do it with `bpy`, for objects is:

```py
# object.type = 'MESH'
object.data.transform(transformMatrix)
```

But when I try to do it over an `empty` type:

```py
# empty.type = 'EMPTY'
empty.data.transform(transformMatrix)
```

I get the error: `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'transform'` because the empty's `data` property is `None`.

**Is there a way to apply the transformations over empties?** If there isn't how can I archive the same results?

> I need to keep the collection linked because the source file changes quite often.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

You have to modify the `empty`'s `location`, `scale` and `rotation` properties with the information contained in the Transformation Matrix. If you used vectors to build the Transformation Matrix, just apply them:

```py
# For location add the vectors
empty.location = empty.location + traslationVect

# For scale assign the vector
empty.scale = scaleVector
```

If you have the transformation matrix you'll have to build the vectors [based on the matrix's elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix)

*PS: I didn't dive into rotations.*